# Можно ли убрать переход текста под checkbox?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какое-нибудь `CSS` свойство что бы текст не переходил под `checkbox`? Чтобы не создавать два отдельных блока для такой верстки.

Либо поделитесь пожалуйста, как Вы решаете данную проблему.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est   reiciendis illum facilis quo minus, veritatis ratione totam corporis,   obcaecati eos laborum maiores! Dolorum minus porro provident amet.  Soluta, corrupti sed?</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код данного блока.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классический вариант через `white-space`:

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est   reiciendis illum facilis quo minus, veritatis ratione totam corporis,   obcaecati eos laborum maiores! Dolorum minus porro provident amet.  Soluta, corrupti sed?</label>
</div>
```

Вариант чуть похуже и менее "адаптивный" через `position: absolute`:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est   reiciendis illum facilis quo minus, veritatis ratione totam corporis,   obcaecati eos laborum maiores! Dolorum minus porro provident amet.  Soluta, corrupti sed?</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, чем второй вариант менее адаптивен?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, менее адаптивный это конечно сильно сказано, да и не для этой задачи, обычно такое используется для стилизации `checkbox` и если надо его увеличить/уменьшить, то приходится менять размер, позиционирование, отступ контейнера, против вариантс с `inline-block`, где нужно поменять только первые 2 пункта ))

Answer (score 0):

Можно флексом

```css
a{
  color:deepskyblue;
}
label{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  display:flex;
  align-items:baseline;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>i have read and agree to<br/> the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a></span>
</label>
```